# Apply Inline Color within Div Tag Typescript React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

In my application, I want to display the objects in the Recharts ToolTip properties, payload in a `<p>` tag.

Within the `payload` array, it includes the color as an attribute called `fill` which I want to color the text in the corresponding `<p>`  See below the `console.log(payload)`

[image]

See code below:

```
  const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label}: TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>) => {
    console.log(payload);
    if(active && payload && payload.length){
      return (
        <div className = "custom-tooltip">
          <p> {payload[0] ? `${payload[0].dataKey} : ${payload[0].value}` : ""}</p>
          <p> {payload[1] ? `${payload[1].dataKey} : ${payload[1].value}` : ""}</p>
          <p> {payload[2] ? `${payload[2].dataKey} : ${payload[2].value}` : ""}</p>
          <p> {payload[3] ? `${payload[3].dataKey} : ${payload[3].value}` : ""}</p>
          <p> {payload[4] ? `${payload[4].dataKey} : ${payload[4].value}` : ""}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have not understood the question but why can't your code be:

```
  const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label}: TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>) => {
    console.log(payload);
    if(active && payload && payload.length){
      return (
        payload.map( pl => <p style="color: " + {pl.fill}>{pl.dataKey} : {pl.value}</p> );
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: when I try this, i get an error under `<p style="color: "` saying: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'Element' and '{ pl: Payload<ValueType, NameType>; "": any; }' Any suggestions?